# Warning: PyPlot is using tkagg backend, which is known to cause crashes on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pyqt5, julia

Does anyone knows how to change the `backend` of `PyPlot` from `"TkAgg"` to `Qt5Agg` in Julia ?

I got this warning when I try to `Using PyPlot` in Julia:

```
julia> using PyPlot
[ Info: Recompiling stale cache file /Users/tonyspc/.julia/compiled/v1.2/PyPlot/oatAj.ji for PyPlot [d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee]
┌ Warning: PyPlot is using tkagg backend, which is known to cause crashes on MacOS (#410); use the MPLBACKEND environment variable to request a different backend.
└ @ PyPlot ~/.julia/packages/PyPlot/4wzW1/src/init.jl:192
```

I tried to use the solution posted here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/454

But it failed:

```
julia> using PyCall
[ Info: Recompiling stale cache file /Users/tonyspc/.julia/compiled/v1.2/PyCall/GkzkC.ji for PyCall [438e738f-606a-5dbb-bf0a-cddfbfd45ab0]

julia> pyimport_conda("PyQt5", "pyqt")
ERROR: PyError (PyImport_ImportModule

The Python package PyQt5 could not be found by pyimport. Usually this means
that you did not install PyQt5 in the Python version being used by PyCall.

PyCall is currently configured to use the Python version at:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

and you should use whatever mechanism you usually use (apt-get, pip, conda,
etcetera) to install the Python package containing the PyQt5 module.

One alternative is to re-configure PyCall to use a different Python
version on your system: set ENV["PYTHON"] to the path/name of the python
executable you want to use, run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia.

Another alternative is to configure PyCall to use a Julia-specific Python
distribution via the Conda.jl package (which installs a private Anaconda
Python distribution), which has the advantage that packages can be installed
and kept up-to-date via Julia.  As explained in the PyCall documentation,
set ENV["PYTHON"]="", run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia. Then,
To install the PyQt5 module, you can use `pyimport_conda("PyQt5", PKG)`,
where PKG is the Anaconda package the contains the module PyQt5,
or alternatively you can use the Conda package directly (via
`using Conda` followed by `Conda.add` etcetera).

) <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
ImportError('No module named PyQt5',)

Stacktrace:
 [1] pyimport(::String) at /Users/tonyspc/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/PyCall.jl:544
 [2] pyimport_conda(::String, ::String, ::String) at /Users/tonyspc/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/PyCall.jl:702
 [3] pyimport_conda(::String, ::String) at /Users/tonyspc/.julia/packages/PyCall/ttONZ/src/PyCall.jl:701
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
```

However I already installed `PyQt5` using `brew install pyqt`

And I don't know why my `matplot library` is located at `python2` directory not the `python3` directory:

```
julia> pyimport("matplotlib").matplotlib_fname()
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc"
```

I have `python2` that comes with default on my Mac, and installed `python3` using `Homebrew`

```
MacBook-Pro:~ tonyspc$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
MacBook-Pro:~ tonyspc$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Should I set the `ENV["PYTHON"]` to `"/usr/local/bin/python3"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I added this to my .bashrc to run every time:

`export MPLBACKEND=qt5agg`

Then after doing the `]build PyCall PyPlot` and restarting julia, it seemed to find the right backend to plot.

My relevant issue I opened (and the answer I got): https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/453#issuecomment-527163934

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ENV["PYTHON"] = "/usr/local/bin/python3"` in a fresh REPL followed by `pkg> build PyCall PyPlot`. This should make PyCall (and therefore also PyPlot) use your local Python 3.

Comment: I tried `ENV["PYTHON"] = "/usr/local/bin/python3"`, `Pkg.build("PyCall")` and `Pkg.build("PyPlot")`still doesn't work.

Comment: How did the error message change? BTW, probably this issue is better suited for [https://discourse.julialang.org](https://discourse.julialang.org) since it doesn't have a  meaningful question - answer structure. Consider opening a thread over there.

Comment: `julia> pyimport_conda("PyQt5", "pyqt")` works but the backend of `PyPlot` is still `TkAgg`. And `julia> pyimport("matplotlib").matplotlib_fname()` still points to my `Python2` directory.

Comment: What does `PyCall.python` or `PyCall.PYTHONHOME` say?

Comment: `"/usr/local/bin/python3"` for `PyCall.python`, `"/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7:/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7"` for `PyCall.PYTHONHOME`

Comment: OMG, I finally solved this. It seems I have `python`, `python2`, `python3` all installed on my Mac. And I only installed `matplotlib` to `python`, after installed it to `python3` using `python3 -mpip install matplotlib` and now everthing works. ```julia> pyimport_conda("PyQt5", "pyqt")
PyObject <module 'PyQt5' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py'>```   ```julia> PyPlot.backend
"Qt5Agg" ```

Comment: My initial guess and your suggestion is correct. Just set `ENV["PYTHON"] = "/usr/local/bin/python3"` then build `PyCall` and `PyPlot` in Pkg mode in Julia. Thanks again for your patience and help !